# Cant seem to get my google maps data scraping to work

Tags: python

When I run this code my spyder terminal doesn't finish and after hitting enter a few times I get this error message :

> {'destination_addresses': [], 'error_message': 'You must use an API
>   key to authenticate each request to Google Maps Platform APIs. For
>   additional information, please refer to
>   http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account', 'origin_addresses': [], 'rows': [],
>   'status': 'REQUEST_DENIED'}

This is my code:

```
def scrape_gmaps_data():

    #import required libraries
    import requests, json

    #enter your api key here
    api_key = 'I tried with my actual API key'

    #take source as input
    source = input()

    #take destination as input
    dest = input()

    #url variable store url
    url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?'

    #get method of requests module
    #return response object

    r = requests.get(url + 'origins = ' + source + '&destinations = ' + dest + '&key = ' + api_key)

    #json method of response object
    #return json format result

    x = r.json()

    #by default driving mode considered

    #print value of x
    print(x)

scrape_gmaps_data()
```

Answer (score 0):

You've to remove the spaces around the '='.

Like:

```py
r = requests.get(url + 'origins=' + source + '&destinations=' + dest + '&key=' + api_key)
```

Hope it helps.